# Doctrine2 DQL Syntax error when ordering by count

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

This is Doctrine Repository function

```
public function mostReadArticleByUser($userId){
    $total = $this->createQueryBuilder('ar')
        ->select('ar.articleId', 'COUNT(ar)')
        ->where('ar.authorId = :userId')
        ->groupBy('ar.articleId')
        ->orderBy('COUNT(ar)', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $total;
}
```

which should be equivalent to this query

```
SELECT article_id, count(id)
    FROM profile_article_reads
    WHERE author_id = 2
    GROUP BY article_id
    Order by count(id) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

When I execute this code I get error

> Error: Expected end of string, got '('
>
> QueryException: SELECT ar.articleId, COUNT(ar) FROM
>   SciProfileBundle\Entity\ProfileArticleReads ar WHERE ar.authorId =
>   :userId GROUP BY ar.articleId ORDER BY COUNT(ar) DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe count funtion accept a field, so try with

```
COUNT(ar.id)
```

instead of:

```
COUNT(ar)
```

Probably for sorting is better using an alias, as example:

```
public function mostReadArticleByUser($userId){
    $total = $this->createQueryBuilder('ar')
        ->select('ar.articleId', 'COUNT(ar.id) as total')
        ->where('ar.authorId = :userId')
        ->groupBy('ar.articleId')
        ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $total;
}
```

Hope this help